# Books on parallel programming in OpenMP and MPI

Tags: parallel-processing

I've been programming with C and FORTRAN for the past 6 years, but I have only done serial programming until now. I would now like to switch to parallel program design, but I haven't really found a book that would help me make this jump. I have looked at Chandra's book on Parallel programming in OpenMP and Michael J. Quinn's book on programming in C with Open Mp and MPI, but I was wondering if there was a better alternative to these two. Thanks in advance!

Prashanth

Comment: check out http://www.hackerbooks.com/books?keywords=parallel+programming

Comment: hackerbooks.com appears to be dead as of 17 May 2013.

Answer (score 6):

I can recommend [Using OpenMP](http://www.amazon.co.uk/Using-OpenMP-Programming-Engineering-Computation/dp/0262533022/ref=sr_1_2?ie=UTF8&qid=1298624872&sr=8-2) by Chapman, Jost and Van de Pas. It's a really good introduction to OpenMP and includes plenty of details on using the language and getting best performance.

[This tutorial](https://computing.llnl.gov/tutorials/parallel_comp/) might also be a useful introduction if you have never experienced parallel programming, it's a good entry to the general concepts and ideas.

Comment: Thank you, Martin! Really appreciate the tutorial as this is the first time I'm doing parallel programming.